# Accessing Locally stored database using google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have a dataset stored locally on my laptop, unfortunately i can't upload it to drive even in zip format, how can i train my model on this dataset(stored locally) using google colab

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `deep-learning` - kindly do not spam the tag (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [Google Drive File Stream](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7329379?hl=en) to mount your Google Drive on your local machine.

Then, you can put files there from your local machine and access them easily in Colab by mounting your Google Drive in the filesystem after running the following snippet:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```